# Return 0 when table does not contain a row that references another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have two tables, **Kurv** and **Kurvtilmeldingsvalg**. Each row in **Kurvtilmeldingsvalg** contains a foreign key to a row in **Kurv**. However, when the **Kurv** is first created, no rows in **Kurvtilmeldingsvalg** exist yet.

I have a script that calculates a number based on some values in **Kurvtilmeldingsvalg**. However, if a row in this table does not yet exist, then the calculation should return 0.

Currently I am using CASE WHEN conditions to calculate the correct sum. However, this does not take non-existing rows in the **Kurvtilmeldingsvalg** table into account.

```
SELECT Kurv.Id AS KurvID,
       ISNULL(SUM(CASE
                      WHEN KurvTilmeldingsvalg.Antal - KurvTilmeldingsvalg.OriginalAntalSolgte < 0 THEN 0
                      ELSE (KurvTilmeldingsvalg.Antal - KurvTilmeldingsvalg.OriginalAntalSolgte)
                  END * nc_valglinjeBase.nc_deltageroptaelling), 1) AS TotalAntal
FROM Kurv
LEFT JOIN KurvTilmeldingsvalg ON Kurv.Id = KurvTilmeldingsvalg.KurvId
LEFT JOIN nc_valglinjeBase ON KurvTilmeldingsvalg.Valglinje = nc_valglinjeBase.nc_valglinjeId
WHERE Kurv.Status in (0,
                      1,
                      2,
                      13/*,14*/)
GROUP BY Kurv.Id
ORDER BY TotalAntal DESC
```

I attempted a solution by doing a subquery inside the WHEN clause:

```
WHEN (Select Count(*) FROM Kurvtilmeldingsvalg INNER JOIN Kurv ON Kurvtilmeldingsvalg.KurvId = Kurv.Id) = 0 THEN 0
```

However i get an error with the following message: "cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery".

Current incorrect output:

[image]

Desired output would return 0 instead of 1. The **Kurv** in this example is not referenced by any rows in **Kurvtilmeldingsvalg**.

How can i return 0 when there are no rows in the **Kurvtilmeldingsvalg** table that reference a row in **Kurv**?

Comment: If you have two tables, why does your query mention three?

Comment: Sorry for not claryfying. The third table 'nc_valglinjeBase' is not relevant in the context of this problem.

Comment: @Leth Yes your third table IS relevant since you join to it and that join will affect your sum calculation. Do yourself and everyone reading your code a favor. Define short but not cryptic aliases for your tables and use them for referencing every column.

Comment: Please use IFNULL(some expression, 0) instead of IFNULL(some expression, 1)

Comment: `IFNULL` isn't a built-in T-SQL function, @RahulBiswas .

Comment: I asked this according to questioner code. Better use COALESCE()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i did this super-fast and filling in the blanks the best i can based on what i think you're trying to do.

```
create table kurv (id int, [status] int)
create table kurvtilmeldingsvalg (kurvid int, antal int, originalantalsolgte int, valglinje int)
create table nc_valglinjebase (nc_valglinjeid int, nc_deltageroptaelling int)

insert into kurv values (1,1)
insert into kurv values (2,0)
insert into kurv values (3,1)
insert into kurv values (4,2)
insert into kurv values (5,13)

insert into kurvtilmeldingsvalg values (1,29,13,101)
insert into kurvtilmeldingsvalg values (2,9,3,101)
insert into kurvtilmeldingsvalg values (3,2,1,102)
insert into kurvtilmeldingsvalg values (3,44,20,102)
insert into kurvtilmeldingsvalg values (2,30,11,103)

insert into nc_valglinjebase values (101,3)
insert into nc_valglinjebase values (102,8)
insert into nc_valglinjebase values (103,5)

select a.id as kurvid
    , case
        when not exists (select 1 from kurvtilmeldingsvalg d where a.id = d.kurvid) then 0
        else isnull(sum(case when b.antal - b.originalantalsolgte < 0 then 0 else b.antal - b.originalantalsolgte end * c.nc_deltageroptaelling), 1)
    end as totalantal
from kurv a
    left join kurvtilmeldingsvalg b on a.id = b.kurvid
    left join nc_valglinjebase c on b.valglinje = c.nc_valglinjeid
where a.status in (0,1,2,13)
group by a.id
order by totalantal desc

drop table kurv
drop table kurvtilmeldingsvalg
drop table nc_valglinjebase
```

tldr; i just used EXISTS to check to see if there are matching rows before checking for NULLs.

it yields this:

```
kurvid      totalantal
----------- -----------
3           200
2           113
1           48
4           0
5           0
```

id 4 and 5 do not have any matching rows in the kurvtilmeldingsvalg table so they result to 0 instead of 1